# ScreenResolution is not being reset Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

Hi guys my resolution upon running my newly build app is always 1920 x 1080 now I want to set it to 1280 x 720 fullscreen resolution . So what I did are this

```
PlayerSettings.defaultScreenWidth = 1280;
PlayerSettings.defaultScreenHeight= 720;
```

and also I set it on my Player Setting just to be sure

[image]

So here's how I find out that my resolution is not resetting

```
resolution.text = Screen.currentResolution.ToString();
```

Here's the solution I tried so far

1.) [Screen.SetResolution](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html)

On this forum

[Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-change-resolution-for-standalone-build.323931/). Where in tried also deleting the registry key in windows but that didn't work . I even tried also deleting the playerprefs but unfortunately that doesn't work also.

Could someone please help me with a remedy to this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you want fullscreen mode set to windowed ? and if so could the resizeable window boolean being false maybe have an impact?

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work @Skdy

Comment: Ok. Can you be specific in what you mean by the resolution not resetting? Is it a reset from your now 1280 x 720 to the 1920 x 1080 or the other way around? Is it inside the editor or during runtime? When do you perform your reset and towards what :)?

Comment: I'm setting my resolution to 1280 x 720 but when i build it , it has a resolution of 1920 x 1080 . And I don't even know why the heck it is set to that resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change it from your Canvas

[image]

For fullscreen settings ,try to follow this guide:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/48778/full-screen-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's running windowed, according to [Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-currentResolution.html), Screen.currentResolution will return the current resolution of the desktop. So it'll show in your UI text 1920 x 1080 because of your desktop resolution. I just tried this and it worked fine:

`void Awake()
{
     Screen.SetResolution(1024, 768, true); // true for setting fullscreen as you wanted
}`

Also according to [Screen.SetResolution](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html), "a resolution switch does not happen immediately; it will actually happen when the current frame is finished".